# fstream object default association

Tags: c++, io

In this program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ob;

    ob<<"hello"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Where is this `hello` written/outputted since `ob` is not associated with any file? Is it the internal file buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is ignored.

When anything is written to a stream, it calls the `overflow` method (or an internal equivalent) of its associated streambuf for each character written. As per [cppreference.com for `std::basic_filebuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/overflow):

> If the associated file is not open (`is_open() == false`), returns `Traits::eof()` before doing anything.

As soon as `overflow` returns an `eof`, the stream's `failbit` is set and all other output is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The [std::ofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) class template has several constructors. This example uses the [std::ofstream default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) to construct an object that is **not** associated to a file.

Excerpt from the reference:

> 1) Default constructor: constructs a stream that is not associated
>   with a file: default-constructs the [std::basic_filebuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) and constructs
>   the base with the pointer to this default-constructed
>   `std::basic_filebuf` member.

@Spencer's answer details what happens then.